# Rails 5 - n+1 query issue inside simple_form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form

I'm trying to resolve every n+1 issue with Bullet gem in my Rails, but I can't figure out this particular problem:

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @course, @lesson]) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.input :start_at, minute_step: 5, start_year: Date.today.year %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.input :end_at, minute_step: 5, start_year: Date.today.year %>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       <!--Here is the problem-->
      <%= f.association :room, :label_method => lambda { |room| "#{room.title} (#{room.building.title})"}%>
       <!--Here is the problem-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= f.association :teacher, :label_method => lambda { |teacher| "#{teacher.first_name} #{teacher.last_name}"},
      collection: @course.teachers%>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-actions text-center">
    <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Form is rendered to **new.html.erb** and **edit.html.erb**. Problem occurs on line with room association where I'm trying to get **room.building.title**.

Here's the screenshoot:
[image: Rails]

As you can see, I only want to display room name with its centre name, but Bullet throws an error. Problem is that I'm using that lambda function so creating a variable in a controller doesn't help (or at least I don't know how to create it properly) since problem occurs inside select box.
Here I'm including my controller:

**lessons_controller.rb**

```
module Admin
  class LessonsController < Admin::AdminController
    helper_method :convert_time, :convert_day
    before_action :set_course
    before_action :set_lesson, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
      @lessons = Lesson.includes(:teacher,:course, :room => :building).where(course_id: @course).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
    #  @course_lessons = @course.lessons.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)

    end

    def new
      #@room = Room.all.includes(:building)
      @lesson = Lesson.new
    end

    def create
      @lesson = Lesson.new(lesson_params)
      @lesson.course = @course
      if @lesson.save
        flash[:success] = "Lesson was created"
        redirect_to admin_course_lessons_path(@course)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end

    def edit

    end

    def update
      if @lesson.update(lesson_params)
        flash[:success] = "Lesson was updated"
        redirect_to admin_course_lessons_path(@course)
      else
        render 'edit'
      end

    end

    def show

    end

    def destroy
      @lesson.destroy
      flash[:danger] = "Lesson was deleted"
      redirect_to admin_course_lessons_path(@course)
    end



    private

    def set_course
      @course = Course.find(params[:course_id])
    end

    def set_lesson
      @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
    end

    def lesson_params
      params.require(:lesson).permit(:start_at,:end_at, :room_id, :teacher_id)
    end
  end
end
```

(Actions relevant for us in this situation are **new** and **edit**)

Here are the relevant models:

**room.rb**

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
  has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
  before_save {self.title = title.upcase_first}
  before_save {self.code = code.upcase}

  validates :title, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50},
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :code, presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 2},
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}
  validates :building_id, presence: true


end
```

**building.rb**

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rooms, dependent: :destroy
  before_save {self.title = title.upcase_first}
  before_save {self.code = code.upcase}

  validates :title, presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 50},
            uniqueness: true
  validates :code, presence: true,
            length: {minimum: 3},
            uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false}

end
```

Sorry for this long post and my lack of knowledge. I will appreciate any feedback.

Comment: Can you try to specify the `collection` option in the `f.association`, and then use `includes` to avoid the N+1 query problem? I mean something like this `f.association :room, :label_method => lambda { |room| "#{room.title} (#{room.building.title})", :collection => Room.includes(:building).all }`

Comment: Yes, that solved this error :) I didn't know that it can be solved this way, thank you very much. (I don't know how to mark your comment as solution so I just vote it up)

Comment: Cool, I will put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the `collection` option using `includes` in the `f.association`. Like this:

`f.association :room, :label_method => lambda { |room| "#{room.title} (#{room.building.title})", :collection => Room.includes(:building).all }`